# How I can extract the python code from the mininet miniedit file?

Tags: python, sdn, mininet, pox

I am working for the software defined network. I am currently using mininet (miniedit) platform to build the SDN topology. I need to extract the python code that generate for a certain topology from the miniedit file (.mn file). Is there any way to extract that code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but the .mn file doesn't contain any code. You have to open the .nm file in MiniEdit and then File → Export Level 2 Script to get the Python code.

Comment: In mininet there will be two option. I can write code in python and run that python code for simulating a SDN topology. There will be another option by using GUI (miniedit). I have made a topology using GUI (mininedit). But I need the equivalent python code for that topology so that I can run as python script. 

Thank you.